# Intersection and union of family of sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm currently working on an assignment for my Discrete Mathematics course (first year).

I'm lost in proving the following:

$\bigcap\limits_{n=1}\limits^\infty [-1,1-\frac{1}{n}]=[-1,0]$

and

$\bigcup\limits_{n=1}\limits^\infty [-1,1-\frac{1}{n}]=[-1,1[$

I found the answer myself, but now I'm having trouble proving my answer without mentioning limits - which I cannot.

Comment: I think the second one is wrong!

Comment: Shoot! I'll think about that one again.

Comment: @David apart from the typo, it is correct.

Comment: @jl00 What typo?  $[-1,1[=[-1,1)$

Comment: Wow! Weird notation!

Answer (score 1):

Let's try the first one:

If $x < -1$, then there is no $n$ such that $x \in [-1, 1-\frac{1}{n}]$. This one was easy. Same goes if $x \geq 1$

If $0 < x < 1$, then there is a big enough $n$ such that $x \notin [-1, 1-\frac{1}{n}]$, you just have to take $n > \frac{1}{x}$

In the remaning case, $-1 \leq x \leq 0$, we have $x \in [-1, 1-\frac{1}{n}]$ for every single value of $n$, so $x$ clearly belongs in the intersection!

Can you do the second one with a similar reasoning (but union rather than intersection)

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The intersection is the set which is included in all of them

$$\bigcap\limits_{n=1}\limits^\infty [-1,1-\frac{1}{n}]=[-1,0]$$

Your sets are $$ [-1,0], [-1,1/2],[-1,2/3],...$$

Note that if $x\in [-1,0]$ then $x\in [-1,1-1/n]$ for all $n$ and vise versa.

For the union $$ \bigcup\limits_{n=1}\limits^\infty [-1,1-\frac{1}{n}]=[-1,1)$$

Notice that $[-1,1)$ includes all your sets and no interval of form $[-1, 1-\epsilon)$ includes all your sets, because you can find some $1/n <\epsilon$ which makes $[-1, 1-\epsilon) \subseteq  [-1, 1-1/n)$

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!